# xhost: man page exists but the command does not work

Tags: aix, xming

In order to resolve one connection issue to Xming, I was trying to set the xhost value as `xhost +<ip>` but it is giving error `ksh: xhost:  not found.` But the man page for the same command exists. The AIX version is 7.1 Technology level 4, service pack 01. What can be the reason for this anomaly?

Comment: You seem to be running the X server on your Windows computer, and the client on the AIX-side. So running xhost on AIX wouldn't change anything. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System Maybe your DISPLAY environment variable is not  set (AIX!telnetd ignores both XDISPLOC and NEWENV)

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Can you guide on how to set the display environment variables?

Comment: Try `echo $DISPLAY`; if that prints nothing, try `export DISPLAY="$(who am i | awk 'print $NF' | tr -d '()'):0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, First "X-Forwarding" was not enabled in my putty window. It can be done from Putty Window - Sessions - Check X11 forwarding.

After this I saw my Xming was rejecting connection request. To solve that, in the Xming installation directory, add the ip of the UNIX server in the "X0.hosts" file.

This should fix the issue.